# MySql to MSSQL conversion

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this query in mysql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ARTICLES`;
CREATE TABLE `ARTICLES` (
  `ART_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ART_ARTICLE_NR` varchar(66) NOT NULL,
  `ART_SUP_ID` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_DES_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_PACK_SELFSERVICE` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_MATERIAL_MARK` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_REPLACEMENT` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_ACCESSORY` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_BATCH_SIZE1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ART_BATCH_SIZE2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ART_ID`),
  KEY `ART_SUP_ID` (`ART_SUP_ID`),
  KEY `ART_DES_ID` (`ART_DES_ID`),
  KEY `ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID` (`ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID`),
  KEY `ART_ARTICLE_NR` (`ART_ARTICLE_NR`(18))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want the MSSQL version of this. I also read about the SSMA converter.

Comment: This site is NOT a code writing service. If you need this urgently you should consider hiring a consultant.

Comment: Thanks but there are some generous people alive too!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('ARTICLES','U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE ARTICLES;
GO

CREATE TABLE ARTICLES 
(
  ART_ID                INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ART_ARTICLE_NR        varchar(66) NOT NULL,
  ART_SUP_ID            INT ,
  ART_DES_ID            INT ,
  ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID   INT ,
  ART_PACK_SELFSERVICE  INT ,
  ART_MATERIAL_MARK     INT ,
  ART_REPLACEMENT       INT ,
  ART_ACCESSORY         INT ,
  ART_BATCH_SIZE1       INT ,
  ART_BATCH_SIZE2       INT 
);
GO

/*
  KEY ART_SUP_ID (ART_SUP_ID),
  KEY ART_DES_ID (ART_DES_ID),
  KEY ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID (ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID),
  KEY ART_ARTICLE_NR (ART_ARTICLE_NR(18))
*/
```

For these indexes you will need to create them in separate SQL Statements. for example SQL Server equivalent of "KEY ART_SUP_ID (ART_SUP_ID)" will be

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SomeIdexName 
ON ARTICLES (ART_SUP_ID)
GO
```

... and so on for each key statement in your mysql statement.

Comment: Do you mind telling me what these lines mean? KEY `ART_SUP_ID` (`ART_SUP_ID`),
  KEY `ART_DES_ID` (`ART_DES_ID`),
  KEY `ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID` (`ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID`),
  KEY `ART_ARTICLE_NR` (`ART_ARTICLE_NR`(18))

Comment: it is creating indexes on these columns.